# JavaScript Object property lookup - does syntax matter?

Tags: javascript, syntax, properties, ecma262

This is a basic question about the JavaScript (ECMAScript) language so I apologize in advance if it's a duplicate (a little searching didn't reveal my exact question).

In ECMAScript we can use two basic syntactic forms to get/set properties on an object and they seem to have the exact same effect.  Since I don't know better, I'll call them "property" and "associative array" notations:

```
var o = {};
// Property notation.
o.foo = 'Foo'; // (set)
o.foo; // => "Foo" (get)
// Associative array notation.
o['bar'] = 'Bar'; // (set)
o['bar']; // => "Bar" (get)
// They seem to be interchangeable.
o['foo']; // => "Foo"
o.bar; // => "Bar"
```

Are there any real differences between these two notations?  Obviously, the associative array notation allows us to lookup dynamically generated keys on the object (and forcibly casts its argument to a string) whereas the property notation uses a literal but is that the only difference?

Comment: Just to add, the "associative array" notation also allows you to have property names that are not proper variable names like `obj["this&that"]`.

Comment: Yes, and also when you wan't to use variable as a key, you have to stick with array notation `object[myVar]`

Comment: Another difference: the dot syntax requires the property name to be valid identifier (e.g. should not start from number, etc) when the [] syntax allows any name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct; they are identical.